# Jquery function is not working, changing bootstrap tabs mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm struggling with an apparently easy problem. I have three tabs on my view and I need to know when the user enter on the last tab.
I use bootstrap tabs and I've tried to resolve this in different solutions, but none of them has worked.

There are my tabs:

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" style="font-size: 18px">
      <li class="active" data-tab="tabTechnicalPresentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"><span class="fa fa-info"></span>  Informations </a></li>
      <li data-tab="tabReferenceNumbers"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"><span class="fa fa-list"></span>  Referencies </a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" aria-controls="menu2" role="tab"><span class="fa fa-car"></span>  Vehicles </a></li>
 </ul> 
     <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <section class="reference-numbers">
           </section>
     </div>

      <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      </div>

      <div id="menu2" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" 
      </div>
```

I have tried to resolve this problem based on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs , as you can see:

```
 1.  <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("a[href='#menu2']").on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        alert('shown - after the tab has been shown');
    });
  });
</script>

 2. <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
    })

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).attr("href");
        if ((target == '#menu2')) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('not ok');
        }
    });
 });
```

I've tried to resolve in different ways, but without success. The alert is not showed. Do you have any idea what am I missing? What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are there errors in console? is jQuery referenced?

Comment: Show the errors

Comment: Why don't you just give an id or class for the <a> tag and then capture the `click` event?

Comment: I don't have errors. The jquery is referenced in my view. I tried to capture the click event, as you have suggested @Developer, but nothing happens.<li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" aria-controls="menu2" role="tab" onclick="test()"><span class="fa fa-car"></span>  Vehicles </a></li>. And the function: function test()
    {
        alert(@ViewBag.FirstMake);
    }

Comment: try `$('[href="#menu2"]').click(function(){alert();});`

Comment: Thanks! It works this way!